# Youtube video embed loop

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

i have made this script and i have 2 strange issue:

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
src="https://youtube.com/embed/kWoxV4HLgKg?rel=0&loop=1&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

The loop=1 don't work and I do not know why.

I was based on: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay

Also, the video does not occupy 100% of the screen but has 2 black bands.

Is it possible to solve these two problems?

Answer (score 1):

Loop will not work in iframes according the following documentation. https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop

About Loop parameter in documentation
Note: This parameter has limited support in the AS3 player and in IFrame embeds, which could load either the AS3 or HTML5 player. Currently, the loop parameter only works in the AS3 player when used in conjunction with the playlist parameter. To loop a single video, set the loop parameter value to 1 and set the playlist parameter value to the same video ID already specified in the Player API URL

The Dimensions of the video are 854px x 480px. You need maintain that aspect ratio to get rid of the black space.

Answer (score 1):

As Ravi mentioned, you need to add it to a playlist in order for it autoplay in an iFrame. To get around this, I've set the playlist to the video itself.

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" 
            src="https://youtube.com/embed/kWoxV4HLgKg?
rel=0&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&playlist=kWoxV4HLgKg&loop=1" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

As for the black bands, it's because the resolution of video does not match the aspect ratio of the screen (as full width would make it widescreen and therefore you'd see black bands on either side). If you try with a video that has a widescreen resolution, you won't see the black bands.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/kWoxV4HLgKg?playlist=kWoxV4HLgKg&autoplay=1&controls=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&loop=1" frameborder="0"
```

Seems that the embedded player can be fickle at times.
Try out different things [HERE](http://www.myonlinelocation.com/YouTube_Play/youtube_embeded_player/) if you like.